# Regarding OAuth1 support of Gmail

Tags: google-oauth

I have used OAuth1+XOauth to connect to Gmail for a custom enterprise application. The application is being used by many customers. Now some of them are reporting that, it's not working correctly for few users in their organizations. I could see in the Gmail Page that Google has deprecated OAuth1 and asked to migrate to OAuth2. If that is the case, May i know, if Google still accepts OAuth1 tokens as i could see that its working for some of the customers?

Please let me know if i can provide more information, as this is a high demanding feature for our enterprise

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

OAuth1 for consumer accounts was shut down last year but we gave a longer grace period for enterprise customers so they can migrate. That is why it is still working but expect it to shut down in the next few months. Is there a reason, you don't want to switch to OAuth2?

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the response :). We have already changed our application to generate OAuth2 tokens. But it would be better if Google can announce  the complete shut-down date for OAuth1 so that we can ask the customers to migrate as few of them were confused why we are asking them to migrate as Google still supporting it
Thank you :-)

Comment: I understand. We should be making a formal announcement to shut it down (in a few months). Team has been trying to make sure most big apps/partners have migrated/have migration plan before that.